# Observable Events Not Received

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a `LocationService` with the following `Observable`:

```
let current: Observable<Location?>
init() {
    …
    current = Observable.combineLatest(selected.asObservable(), user) { $0 ?? $1.flatMap { Location(coordinate: $0, name: "Nearby") } }.distinctUntilChanged(==).debug()
    …
}
```

In a view model I transform the observable like so:

```
let distance: Driver<String?>
required init(model: Media, dependencies: Dependencies) {
    …
    distance = dependencies.location.current.filterNil().map { media.place.coordinate.distance(to: $0.coordinate) }.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil)
    …
}
```

In a view I user this to drive the UI:

```
viewModel.distance.map { $0 == nil }.drive(distanceView.rx.isHidden).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

By adding `.debug()` to the end of the `current` observable I can see that it is definitely emitting an event, but the views don't receive it because they are subscribing after it is emitted. Why don't they automatically receive the last emitted event?

> 2017-10-24 14:33:42.650: LocationService.swift:39 (init()) ->
>   subscribed 2017-10-24 14:33:42.975: LocationService.swift:39 (init())
>   -> Event next(Optional(Service.Location(coordinate: Service.Coordinate(latitude: 51.509979999999999, longitude:
>   -0.13370000000000001), name: "Nearby", radius: nil))) 2017-10-24 14:33:50.038: LocationService.swift:39 (init()) -> subscribed

Comment: when you update the UI do you run in on the main thread?

Comment: Try adding more debug statements to the other observables. At what point does it emit any new values?

Comment: @TNguyen Yes, it is a `Driver`. @Yannick New values are received by the subscribers. I want to also receive the last value before subscription.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Subjects](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) and especially the [ReplaySubjects](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Subjects/ReplaySubject.swift)?

Comment: Driver should replay though: `- share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected) sharing strategy`

Comment: If either of the Observables in your `combineLatest` operator is a hot Observable, then perhaps they emit a value before there is any connected subscriber. By the time your view subscribes, it will replay all elements that were previously observed by another subscriber. But since there was no subscriber, there's nothing to replay.